# Service bus message Error deserializing the object of type System.String but message format is correct json

Tags: c#, json, azureservicebus

Service bus message Error deserializing the object of type System.String but message format is correct json.

Send message to topic using code -

```
 topicClient = new TopicClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName);

                // Create a new message to send to the topic.
                string messageBody = string.Format("{{ \"Id\":\"{0}\",\"Name\":\"{1}\" }}", "121", "Demo");
                var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

                // Send the message to the topic.
                await topicClient.SendAsync(message);
```

Message into service bus topic looks like -

```
{ "Id":"121","Name":"Demo" }
```

While reading message from Topic getting below error -

```
string currentMessageData = currentMessage.GetBody<string>();
```

> There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The
>   input source is not correctly formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that your message is being written as a `stream` and not a `string`.

Instead of

```
string currentMessageData = currentMessage.GetBody<string>();
```

try

```
Stream stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string currentMessageData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```